# SQL Server 2014 Set values to lookup table ID

Tags: sql-server

If I have an address table and a cities lookup table and the address table has the cities in text instead of a foreign key, how would I replace the text with its counterpart in the lookup table?

Example:

Table `luCities`:

```
ID    Name
--------------------
1     New Orleans
2     Portland
3     Seattle
```

Table `Addresses`:

```
ID    Street         City           State   Zip
--------------------------------------------------    
1     123 main st.   New Orleans    OR      96556
```

should become

```
ID    Street         CityId         State   Zip
--------------------------------------------------    
1     123 main st.   1              OR      96556
```

I have roughly 250 rows to match multiple cities with, so I'm hoping that a single UPDATE/SET statement can be used to match and modify them.

Comment: But New Orleans is not in Oregon...

Comment: Keep in mind that a list of city names is only sort of decent. You really should also include the state with the city so you know what state it belongs to. Otherwise you end up with nonsense like New Orleans, OR. And there are lots of city names in more than 1 state.

Comment: This is more of a holdover from an old database I'm migrating- Soon I'll be getting access to one with all states and cities in them, then I can further validate it based on their connections.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are looking for an update-join. If you add CityID to addresses as a FK to luCities, you can run this:

```
UPDATE Addresses SET
CityID = c.ID
FROM Addresses A
inner join luCities C on A.City = C.Name
```

Once everything looks correct, you can drop the old City column if you like.

Comment: Yup, this was it. Thanks!